# Mediawiki Categories contain no pages

Tags: mediawiki

I recently installed a wiki on my server using mediawiki. Whenever I add a page to a category the category is linked correctly on the bottom of the page. However, if I open the category page my content page is just not added. It says "This category currently contains no pages or media." even though it links correctly. Did I make a mistake? Reinstalling several times didn't help an the category appears under "unused categories".

Comment: I just installed v1.39.0 and just added a few categories.  I expected a list of pages a category has been added to. All category pages are empty however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that might help is to [purge](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Purge) the category page.

Another possible solution is the maintenance script "[Rebuildall.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Rebuildall.php)". It helped me some days ago after I had empty categories after importing content to one of my wikis.

Comment: rebuildall.php helped. Thank you very much! I tried purge before but somehow it wouldn't work. I'm probably going to add a cronjob for this :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue but don't know how to run command line on shared hosting. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you can use cronjobs on your shared hosting you can use it to run the script. Otherwise I recommend talking to your hoster.

Comment: I executed script rebuildall.php in 1.39 but still all category pages are empty.

Comment: When I add something to the non existing category page and save it then the list of pages are shown. Is there a way to automatically create the category page without any content but just to show the list of pages?

Comment: The list of pages is shown regardless of whether you have put content on the category page. If this is not the case on your wiki: Which MediaWiki version do you use?